# Collection inside Classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sublimetext3

I have the following code snippet,

```
/*
* The drink class, which defines the characteristics of the drink, in its simplest form, has its name
*/
class Drink {
    constructor( drinkName ) {
        this.Name = drinkName;
    }
}

/*
* The Customer class contains the properties of the customer along with the drinks preferred by the customer.
*/
class Customer {
    constructor( name, drinks ) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.PreferredDrinks = drinks;
        }
    }
function lazyBartender() {

    var customers = [];
    var c1 = new Customer('Cust1', [new Drink( 'n3' ), new Drink( 'n7' ), new Drink( 'n5' ), new Drink( 'n2' ), new Drink( 'n9' )] );
    customers.push(c1);
    return customers;
}
```

when i put the following statement, i get the output as

`console.log(lazyBartender());`

```
[ Customer {
    Name: 'Cust1',
    PreferredDrinks: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Instead if i use the `return c1;` inside the lazyBartender() method and then call console.log, I get the following output

```
Customer {
  Name: 'Cust1',
  PreferredDrinks: 
   [ Drink { Name: 'n3' },
     Drink { Name: 'n7' },
     Drink { Name: 'n5' },
     Drink { Name: 'n2' },
     Drink { Name: 'n9' } ] }
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

What is wrong in the code, because if I implement in this way, I am getting a stackoverflow exception in my code. can anyone point out the mistake if any?

The full source code is as given below,

```
/*
* The drink class, which defines the characteristics of the drink, in its simplest form, has its name
*/
class Drink {
    constructor( drinkName ) {
        this.Name = drinkName;
    }
}

/*
* The Customer class contains the properties of the customer along with the drinks preferred by the customer.
*/
class Customer {
    constructor( name, drinks ) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.PreferredDrinks = drinks;
    }
}

class DrinkPref {
    constructor( name, prefCount ) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Preference = prefCount || 0;
    }

    //Getter
    get prefCt() {
        return this.Preference;
    }

    increment() {
        this.Preference += 1;
    }
}

function doIncrement ( collection, key ) {

    var existingItem = collection.find( function( value, index ) {
        return value.Name == key;
    } );

    if( existingItem == undefined ) {
        existingItem = new DrinkPref( key, 0 );
        collection.push( existingItem );
    }
    existingItem.increment();

}

function getMax ( collection, key ) {
    var maxValue = -Infinity;

    collection.sort( function( a, b ) {
        return a.prefCt() > b.prefCt();
    } );
}

function getMinDrinksForAlCustomers(customers) {
    var drinkChoices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        var customer = customers[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < customer.PreferredDrinks.length; j++) {
            doIncrement( drinkChoices, customer.PreferredDrinks[j].Name );
        }
    }

    getMax( drinkChoice );

    return drinkChoices;
}

function lazyBartender() {

    var c1 = new Customer('Cust1', [new Drink( 'n3' ), new Drink( 'n7' ), new Drink( 'n5' ), new Drink( 'n2' ), new Drink( 'n9' )] );
    var c2 = new Customer('Cust2', [new Drink('n5')] );
    var c3 = new Customer('Cust3', [new Drink('n2'), new Drink('n3')] );
    var c4 = new Customer('Cust4', [new Drink('n4')] );
    var c5 = new Customer('Cust5', [new Drink('n3'), new Drink('n4'), new Drink('n3'), new Drink('n5'), new Drink('n7'), new Drink('n4')] );
    var customers = [c1, c2,c3, c4, c5];

    return lazyBartender( customers );
}
console.log(lazyBartender());
```

Getting the below exception

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: I can't [reproduce](http://jsbin.com/xucisifaro/edit?js,console) this stackoverflow.

Comment: I have added the full source code and the exception occuring from sublime-text editor console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `lazyBartender` to this- removing the recursive call in the return statement :

```
function lazyBartender() {

    var c1 = new Customer('Cust1', [new Drink( 'n3' ), new Drink( 'n7' ), new Drink( 'n5' ), new Drink( 'n2' ), new Drink( 'n9' )] );
    var c2 = new Customer('Cust2', [new Drink('n5')] );
    var c3 = new Customer('Cust3', [new Drink('n2'), new Drink('n3')] );
    var c4 = new Customer('Cust4', [new Drink('n4')] );
    var c5 = new Customer('Cust5', [new Drink('n3'), new Drink('n4'), new Drink('n3'), new Drink('n5'), new Drink('n7'), new Drink('n4')] );
    var customers = [c1, c2,c3, c4, c5];

    return customers;
}
```

I have no idea what you were trying to accomplish with the recursive call (`return lazyBartender( customers )`) - `lazyBartender` doesn't take any arguments, and it doesn't have any base case, so it would just keep calling itself over and over again, giving you the error.

Maybe you meant to do `return getMinDrinksForAlCustomers(customers)` instead?